# When adding a modal element to each element in feed all the modals refer only to the last object in the array

Tags: next.js

[image]

Each modal needs to have the details of the object passed to it but all modals have the details of the last object on the array.
lets just say the array
0
:
{id: '6531135faa18f3f01fb061b9', name: 'My Restaurant', rating: 4.5, cuisines: Array(0), latitude: 13.344024, …}
1
:
{id: '6531178da2ed932b6d062eed', name: 'Her Restaurant', rating: 3.4, cuisines: Array(0), latitude: 13.344027, …}

all modals only contain the details of the last object with name Her Restaurant